# Bash: Prune find results using absolute paths

Tags: bash, cron, putty

I'm running a script to look through some folders for a file type, but I need to prune a few folders. The script works when I run it via PuTTy using relative filepaths, but when I add in the absolute file paths so I can run it as a cron task, it doesn't prune correctly.

Here's my command:

```
/bin/find . -not \( -path "./Ready" -prune \) -not \( -path "./Loading" -prune \) -not \( -path "./Backups" -prune \) -name "*.txt"
```

However, when I replace "./" with the full path, it returns results for files in the folders it shouldn't be searching.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean if you replace **all** occurences of `./` with full path?

Comment: Yeah, so I have $base=the full path. It searches all the folders if I do this:

`/bin/find . -not \( -path "$base/Ready" -prune \) -not \( -path "$base/Loading" -prune \) -not \( -path "base/Backups" -prune \) -name "*.txt"`

Comment: As I answered below:  `/bin/find "$base" -not \( -path "$base/Ready" -prune \) -not \( -path "$base/Loading" -prune \) -not \( -path "$base/Backups" -prune \) -name "*.txt"`

Comment: @amy, no you did not replace the `./` right after the find itself... cmks was right from the start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that the pattern match test applies to the whole file name,
>   starting from one of the start points named on the command line.  It
>   would only  make
>                 sense to use an absolute path name here if the relevant start point is also an absolute path.  This means that this command
>   will never match anything:
>
> find bar -path /foo/bar/myfile -print

You need to use the absolute path as search base too, so exchange the first `.` (the starting point of the search) with the same absolute path you use for the `-path` arguments.

```
find /usr -path "/usr/src/linux*" -prune -o -path "/usr/inclu*" -prune -o -name "*.txt" -print
```

This will list all `*.txt` files but the content of any directory starting with `/usr/src/linux*` or `/usr/inclu*`.

Comment: Aha, that did it! Thanks! (If only every problem was this simple.)